# How to get available virtual memory regions for WinDBG preview TTD trace session?

Tags: windbg, dbgeng

I am writing dbgeng client and try to enumerate available virtual memory for time travel debugging session.

Dbgeng API have `IDebugDataSpaces2::QueryVirtual` method, it's works great for live user-mode debugging sessions, but does not works for TTD trace session replay.
When I try to call it, I recieve 0x8000ffff (E_UNEXPECTED) error.

Looks like `!address` and `!vprot` commands from windbg preview gui have same issue

```
0:000> !vprot 0
ERROR: !vprot: extension exception 0x8000ffff.
    "QueryVirtual failed"
0:000> !address

        BaseAddress      EndAddress+1        RegionSize     Type       State                 Protect             Usage
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is `IDebugDataSpaces4::GetValidRegionVirtual` method. It works, but TOO long (looks like it tries to check every page manually). Looks like `IDebugDataSpaces4::GetNextDifferentlyValidOffsetVirtual` also works wrong for TTD replay.

Does dbgeng API have other methods to enumerate valid memory ranges for process?
Or maybe there is another way to get this info from IDX or RUN files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment some information available in live debug and dump files are not available in TTD. The two main features are: a) QueryVirtual does not work; b) Process and thread security token information are not saved.
I used QueryVirtual a lot in my Debug extension and I made changes to deal with it. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I try to implement thrid party debugger plugin. This debugger API requires to report all available memory regions before actual memory access operations.

Looks like I need elaborate some other way to solve this task.